# Nginx Plus API back end server drain mode

Tags: nginx

I am working with Nginx Plus API and trying to put the backend servers in drain mode and while doing this via curl getting below error ,

"method":"PATCH","error":{"status":415,"text":"json error","code":"JsonError"},

format which I followed : 
.\curl.exe -u username -X PATCH -d '{"drain":true}' baseserverurl

Answer (score 0):

have to use as  -X PATCH -d '{\"drain\":true}'